# Sending WatchKit Voice recognition's text to another interface controller

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am having an issue sending dictated text to another interface controller.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)voiceRecognition {

    [self presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:nil allowedInputMode:WKTextInputModePlain completion:^(NSArray *results) {

        NSLog(@"results: %@", results);

        NSString *wordKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",results];
        NSDictionary *dict = @{@"kWord":wordKey};
        [self pushControllerWithName:@"Dictionary" context:dict];

    }];
}
```

Logs:

> Watch Extension[3185:2835671] results: ( Hello )

Getting data from other Interface controller:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)context;
    [_word setText:dict[@"kWord"]];

    NSLog(@"The Word is %@",[dict description]);

}
```

Logs:

> Watch Extension[3185:2835671] The Word is {
>           kWord = "(\n    Hello\n)";
>       }

Here is a screen shot that shows my problem:

[image]

The `(` is supposed to show the word `Hello`. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `stringWithFormat` to format an *array* as a string.

This took `["Hello"]` and correctly converted it to the literal `"(\n    Hello\n)"`

Because that string has a newline, it can't be displayed on a single line.  Your Storyboard `WKInterfaceLabel` number of lines is likely set to 1, so it would only show the first line, which is `(`.

**How can you fix this?**

- If you're only interested in the first word, use `results.firstObject` and pass that single word as the string value for your `kWord` key.

  ```
  NSDictionary *dict = @{@"kWord": results.firstObject};
  ```
- Otherwise, pass the *entire* array as the value, and have the destination interface controller handle the array of results as needed.

  ```
  NSDictionary *dict = @{@"kWord": results};
  ```

*You also may want to change the number of lines to show the entire dictation text, to handle the case where the text wouldn't fit on a single line.*

**Other options:**

If you actually intended to send the dictated text as a single string of words, you can use

```
NSString *wordKey = [results componentsJoinedByString:@" "]
```